# Update multiple rows of one column in data table using C#

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I need to update multiple rows of one column in data table with one statement with looping every row taking too much time.

Ex: I want to update "Result" column in "Students Information" data table, with condition who are got marks less than 60%

My main intention is save processing time to update table.

```
        foreach (DataRow dr in studentsInfo.Select("Marks < 60"))
        {
            dr["Result"] = "Fail";
        }
```

Comment: please can you post your code?

Comment: Sorry! updated question

Comment: define "too much time" and how many students you have.

Comment: You're obviously not using the right tool to bulk update data. If you're going to get this faster (which I doubt) the next challenge will be how to update the actual database smoothly off of the datatable.

Comment: each `DataRow` is a separate object, changing some cell's value requires access to the `DataRow` instance. So if you have thousands of `DataRows`, you need thousands of accesses to update the value. There is no other way and if any exists, it just blinds you from the actual happening. Unless if you want to update the data to some database, then the way to push data to database is not via a set of `DataRows` (so you don't need to loop through rows and update value), instead build and run some commands directly.

Comment: Can you suggest me to those commands